# Autodesk Forge Model Derivative API: how to tying geometory in OBJ File with property

Tags: forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I was successful in downloading Geometory Data of Revit Model ([following this tutorial](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/extract-geometry-from-source-file/)).

And I was successful in getting Revit Model Properties ([tutorial](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/extract-data-from-source-file/)).

But I can not find key for tying geometory with property.

Anyone know key for tying? or Anyone know how to tie both data ?

Answer (score 0):

The Revit Element `UniqueId` property is included in the Forge translated result. In the Forge data, it is stored as the `externalId`.

An example of accessing the Forge information in the viewer in order to transmit changes back to the Revit BIM is provided by the `roomedit3d` sample:

https://github.com/jeremytammik/roomedit3d

Look at the `Roomedit3dTranslationTool` implementation:

https://github.com/jeremytammik/roomedit3d/blob/master/www/js/extensions/Roomedit3dTranslationTool.js

Comment: i added your question and this answer to the roomedit3d readme docs at https://github.com/jeremytammik/roomedit3d#1-autodesk-forge-model-derivative-api--how-to-tie-forge-geometry-in-obj-file-with-revit-bim-property

Comment: Thank you Jeremy. I understood that UniqueId is converted to externalId.